# JSF - JUnit FacesContext mock Test

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, junit, easymock

I have some problem with wirint testcase for my JSF app. So i want to test my logout method:

```
            FacesContext context = EasyMock.createMock(FacesContext.class);
            String userName = "testUserName";
            HttpSession session = EasyMock.createMock(HttpSession.class);
            ExternalContext ext = EasyMock.createMock(ExternalContext.class);
            EasyMock.expect(ext.getSession(true)).andReturn(session);
            EasyMock.expect(context.getExternalContext()).andReturn(ext).times(2);
            context.getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
            EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();           

            EasyMock.replay(context);
            EasyMock.replay(ext);
            EasyMock.replay(session);

            loginForm = new LoginForm();
            loginForm.setUserName(userName);
            String expected = "login";
            String actual = loginForm.logout();
            context.release();

            Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
            EasyMock.verify(context);
            EasyMock.verify(ext);
            EasyMock.verify(session);
```

My logout method is:

```
    public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/authentication/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

My problem is that i got a nullpointer exception here:
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once()
How should it be properly tested? I guess it is something with the mocks but i couldnt find a solution, how could i mock properly the FacesContext in this case

Comment: Why do you want to test `logout()`? It has no logic and it only uses methods from `javax.faces` (that you should assume were properly tested by the team developping it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the above work you could use for example **PowerMock** which is a framework that allows you to extend mock libraries like **EasyMock** with extra capabilities. In this case it allows you to mock the static methods of `FacesContext`.

If you are using Maven, use following [link](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/EasyMock_maven) to check the needed dependency setup.

Annotate your JUnit test class using these two annotations. The first annotation tells JUnit to run the test using `PowerMockRunner`. The second annotation tells **PowerMock** to prepare to mock the `FacesContext` class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FacesContext.class })
public class LoginFormTest {
```

Now go ahead and mock `FacesContext` using **PowerMock** like you would do for the other classes. Only difference is that this time you perform `replay()` and `verify()` on the class not the instance.

```
@Test
public void testLogout() {

    // mock all static methods of FacesContext
    PowerMock.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);

    FacesContext context = EasyMock.createMock(FacesContext.class);
    ExternalContext ext = EasyMock.createMock(ExternalContext.class);

    EasyMock.expect(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).andReturn(context);
    EasyMock.expect(context.getExternalContext()).andReturn(ext);

    ext.invalidateSession();
    // expect the call to the invalidateSession() method
    EasyMock.expectLastCall();
    context.release();

    // replay the class (not the instance)
    PowerMock.replay(FacesContext.class);
    EasyMock.replay(context);
    EasyMock.replay(ext);

    String userName = "testUserName";
    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm.setUserName(userName);

    String expected = "/authentication/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    String actual = loginForm.logout();
    context.release();

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);

    // verify the class (not the instance)
    PowerMock.verify(FacesContext.class);
    EasyMock.verify(context);
    EasyMock.verify(ext);
}
```

I've created a [blog post](https://www.codenotfound.com/easymock-unit-testing-facescontext-powermock-junit.html) which explains the above code sample in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
FacesContext context = EasyMock.createMock(FacesContext.class);
```

does not change the return value from this (in the class being tested):

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
```

You need to extend `FacesContext` then call the protected method `setCurrentInstance` with your mocked FacesContext.